# Hacking select multiple in javascript, flicke

Tags: javascript

I've hacked html's < select multiple > with javascript, according to my customer's specifications:

- clicking an item *only* toggles *that* item's selected status.
- other selected items stay selected.

The little bit of javascript remembers all selected values.
When the user clicks, only the option he clicks will be selected.
The javascript selects the options he remembers.

However, it causes a flicker effect. I doubt there is any solution for this, but I felt I had to ask just in case, does anyone know of a way to delay the rendering, or any other solution to accomplish this, without a flicker?

Best regards.

EDIT: here is the code

```
var choices=new Array();
function prepmulti(){
    var m=document.querySelectorAll('select');
    for(var i=0;i<m.length;i++)
        if(m[i].id!=''){
            m[i].onclick=toggle;
            choices.push(new Array());
        }
}
function toggle(){
    var sel, x;
    for(var i=0; i<this.options.length;i++)
        if(this.options[i].selected){
            sel=i;
            break;
        }
    if((x=choices[this.id].indexOf(sel))<0)
        choices[this.id].push(sel);
    else{
        choices[this.id].splice(x, 1);
        this.options[sel].selected=false;
        }
    for(i=0;i<choices[this.id].length;i++)
            this.options[choices[this.id][i]].selected=true;
}

<body onload='prepmulti();'>
```

The select multiples have ids 0, 1, 2, etc... If you give them other ids, the code must be modified a little.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: You should use `getElementsByTagName` instead of `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flicker you see is from it changing the selected option(s) then repainting - unfortunately I don't think this is avoidable in most browsers.

In Chrome you can bind `onmousedown` on the select, use `preventDefault` and then set the event `target`'s `selected` to the opposite of what it is.

```
var m=document.querySelectorAll('select');
for(var i=0;i<m.length;i++)
{
    m[i].onmousedown = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VDnQK/

This only works in Chrome, though. IE supports preventDefault for `select` but `e.target` returns the `select` rather than the `option` element.
FireFox doesn't seem to support preventDefault for select (at least, I can't get it to work).